# Remotely delete and map network drive for a user

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, network-drive

I am trying to remotely unmap and map a network drive for users on my domain. I need it to work by searching a key phrase in the drive path (\"phrase"\folder...) While not knowing the letter of the drive.. Here is what I have done so far:

```
$DestPC = "PC Name"
$Drive = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -ComputerName $DestPC | Select PSComputerName, Name, ProviderName | Where { $_.ProviderName -Like "*Phrase*" };
$DriveLetter = $Drive.Name;
"net use $DriveLetter /del`nnet use $DriveLetter $FolderNew" | Out-File -FilePath \\$DestPC\C$\ITS\DriveMap.bat -Encoding Ascii;
SCHTASKS /CREATE /S $DestPC /SC OnLogon /TN .\ITS\DriveTask /TR ITS\DriveMap.bat /F /Z
```

My current plan is to use WMI to grab the drive letter from the PC, but some PCs dont seem to share that info remotely, and only seem to work when the command is run locally.  Issue is, we don't have PSRemoting enabled on our network.

Comment: Where is that *DriveMap.bat* coming from? Can you just not write the entirety of the script inside a ps1 then call on it using schtasks?

Comment: So if you're just going to make a scheduled task on the remote machine that runs a file you put on their computer, why not just write the script to perform the lookup and change on the local machine and run the script with the scheduled task?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala The bat file is written to the remote PC in his 4th line.

Comment: ahh, gotcha. Regardless, you can still write the logic in the remote script and have it be called on using schtasks.